# How to code summary row in ASP.NET Razor table?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, razor

I have a table built out in a Razor view that goes like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.column1)</td>
        ...
        ...
    </tr>
}
```

I want to add a summary of the table at the end, something like:

```
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Sum(a => a.column1)</td>
    ...
    ...
</tr>
```

That actually works but it doesn't use my data annotations since I'm not using DisplayFor(). I tried placing the Model.Sum within a DisplayFor() but the code doesn't work. Can anyone point me towards a solution?

Comment: You could write an HTML helper that examined the property lambda, performed the sum() and utilized your data annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an HTML helper that examined the property lambda, performed the sum() and utilized your data annotations.

### View Model

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display( Name = "My Display Name" )]
    public int Bar {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Baz {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

### View

```
@model IEnumerable<FooViewModel>

@* Razor engine prefers this syntax? think generic may confuse it *@
@(Html.SumFor<FooViewModel>( o => o.Bar ))
```

### Helper Extension

This is far from perfect. An improvement would be to allow any type to be summed without having to provide a different method for every summable type.

```
public static IHtmlString SumFor<TEnumerableItem>( this HtmlHelper helper, 
    Expression<Func<TEnumerableItem, int>> expression ) {

    // get metadata through slightly convoluted means since the model
    // is actually a collection of the type we want to know about

    // lambda examination
    var propertyName = ( (MemberExpression)expression.Body ).Member.Name;

    // property metadata retrieval
    var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current
        .GetMetadataForProperty( null, typeof( TEnumerableItem ), propertyName );

    // make an assumption about the parent model (would be better to enforce 
    // this with a generic constraint somehow)
    var ienum = (IEnumerable<TEnumerableItem>)helper.ViewData.Model;

    // get func from expression
    var f = expression.Compile();

    // perform op
    var sum = ienum.Sum( f );

    // all model metadata is available here for the property and the parent type
    return MvcHtmlString.Create( 
       string.Format( "<div>Sum of {0} is {1}.</div>", metadata.DisplayName, sum )
    );
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I can read that but it's way above my current expertise level. How would I go about calculating the sum after passing the lamba to this function?

Comment: It might be easiest to just pass the original enumerable AND the property lambda. There is probably a more elegant way of doing it, but that would work. The property lambda lets you get the data annotations, and the enumerable gives you the actual value.

Comment: A custom display template might also work for you: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: I'm all for learning your original implementation 'cause I actually really like the idea. The part I'm stuck on is how to perform the Sum with this helper/expression nonsense.

Comment: Haha, yeah I'm actually trying to figure out an elegant way of doing it. I'll post an update if I find something good.

Comment: P.S. The only reason I'm trying to avoid the partial views thing is that, AFAIK, it negates the whole point of my data annotations and I LOVE having the Model and it's display settings defined in one single place (it just make so much sense!!!).

Comment: Check out the update. I've done some limited testing and this does work.

Comment: Trying to run this and I get: "No overload for method 'SumFor' takes 1 arguments."

Comment: Is it available to the view as an extension method? You have to modify your web.config for the view directory to include the namespace where the extension resides.

Comment: Ok, that actually seems to work. It outputs "Sum of is 15991". So it doesn't look like DisplayName is working. Nor does it use my Data Annotation format. I really appreciate the help so far and I'll try to turn this into what I need but def would appreciate any other help/insight you can give. Thanks again.

Comment: I solved the DisplayFormat issue by simply changing string.Format(...) to string.Format(metadata.DisplayFormatString, sum).

Comment: Cool. Obviously you can now put anything you want in that helper, since you have access to all the metadata of the collection, the collection item, and the individual property. It's pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand you... Add a property to your model and use your required DataAnnotation:

```
    [MyDataAnnotation]
    public int Sum
    {
        get
        {
            var sum = 0;
            foreach(var item in this)
            {
                sum += item.Value;
            }    
            return sum;     
        }
    }
```

Then use displayfor with this property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery Datatables plugin.  In Javasript you get loads of 'freebies' with this then just by turning on/off your table config properties.  So you can get a search box at top of table - automatic sorting columns by alphabetic for example you you also get an info line at bottom of table - something like "Showing 1 of 8 entries"